# Rails 3 - avoid duplication of controller code that generates a partial used in views generated by several other controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is a noob question. My applets_controller has partials that will be called from views associated with other controllers.

(e.g. applets_controller _applet1.html.erb called from user_home_controller show.html.erb)

my link in show.html.erb is:

```
<%= render :partial => "applets/applet1" %>
```

I would prefer not to duplicate code to get variables from the applets_controller in all of the controllers of the views that will call the applet. How can i avoid doing this? I suppose i could transfer much of the code to the application_controller or to models. Is there a simpler solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could put the relevant code & output into a Helper, and change your calls in the partial (_applet1.html.erb) to refer to that helper. That way, it would be available anywhere in your application. Depending on which helper you put it into, you may have to include a line to `include AppletHelper` or something similar.